# Config transforms in non-web applications - part 1 turn off debug

Tags: c#, app-config

How do we disable debug mode in an app that is not a web app like a windows service or console app?

compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)"

I know this goes in system.web for web apps but does it work the same way in a service? If not how can we disable DEBUG mode so that code is not released in debug mode?

Comment: I've used [SlowCheetah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms) to do this.

Comment: I would think debug mode is mostly about having `DEBUG` defined, generating debug symbol files (pdb) and disabling compiler optimization options... all of those things would be controlled by configuration specific project settings at compile-time, not as an application setting at runtime. So, while transforming app.config files is possible, it is not useful for turning off "debug"

Comment: Thank you. You are probably correct and I am thinking more towards creating a separate config to satisfy the no-debug requirement that I want when I push this through Azure DevOps. I am still curious as to how this might work for non-web apps.